# Using Named Keys in Array C# MVC razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a javascript array that is being passed back to the controller

```
amount_array[]
```

and it contains different named keys such as

```
amount_array['start_date'] , amount_array['end_date']
```

with more variables like that in the array

Is there any way to set a array up in C# on the controller to call the start and end date from the array by name?

Or will I just have to call by the position in the array?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you pass these as properties of a Javascript 'object' instead of as an array, and then have a class in C# that matches it. Take that C# object as your parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a javascript array

No, you don't have a javascript array. In javascript arrays must have integer 0 based indexes. What you have is a javascript object with 2 properties: `start_date` and `end_date`.

So you define a view model to match this structure:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action to take this view model and do some processing with it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // use model.Start_Date and model.End_Date here
    ...
}
```

and finally a javascript function to invoke this controller action (using AJAX for example):

```
var amount_array = {
    start_date: new Date(2012, 8, 1).toUTCString(),
    end_date: new Date(2012, 8, 31).toUTCString()
};
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: amount_array,
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```